# Where is the `unicode` class located in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, location

I have the following code snippet in code I'm trying to run:

```
digits = 4 if isinstance(src, unicode) else 2
```

I get an error, because `unicode` is unrecognized. I've searched Google for a `unicode` class in Python, but without luck.
How do I import or locate `unicode` such that this code snippet makes sense ? `src` is a `bytes` object, i.e. a sequence of bytes, and the purpose is to detect whether it contains ASCII or Unicode characters.

Comment: In Python 3, `str` is the unicode type.

Comment: What is string type then ?

Comment: It's the same.  python3 strings are are sequences of unicode characters